Could not able to download the HTML content as PDF in ASP.NET Web API
I have designed a html in the C#, on .NET and using Entity Framework., I have a PDF documents which are stored base64 encoded.
I should be able to get the full html string after this I am downloading this html string as a PDF using PuppeteerSharp;. The PDF is downloading correctly but the PDF's within that are not returned - a blank space is showing up instead.
Here is my HTML code, tag where I am displaying PDF. The HTML is very big so I posted just a small portion:
<div class='viewer'>
    <embed src='data:application/pdf;base64,{HtmlEncode(data[0].BasicInformationBytearray)}' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%' />
</div>

Once the HTML string is generated with the dynamic data I am sending this to conversion of HTML string to PDF:
// Generate HTML string
string htmlString = GenerateHtmlString(memberObservations);

var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
var revisionInfo = await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);

var launchOptions = new LaunchOptions
                {
                    ExecutablePath = revisionInfo.ExecutablePath,
                    Headless = true // Set to true to run in headless mode (no GUI)
                };

using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(launchOptions))
using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
{
    // Set the HTML content
    await page.SetContentAsync(htmlString);

    // Generate PDF
    byte[] pdfBytes = await page.PdfDataAsync(new PdfOptions
                    {
                        Format = PaperFormat.A4,
                        PrintBackground = true,
                    });

    // Return the PDF file as a response
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfBytes)
                    };

    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = $"Report_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.pdf"
                    };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

    return ResponseMessage(response);
}

GenerateHtmlString is the method where whole HTML string is generated and returned.
First the PDF's are stored in storage account which are coming as a URLs. I thought this was the issue so I saved the PDFs in the local database itself as varbinary, this also did not came. I tried iFrame instead of embed tag the issue remained same.
Could anybody please help me resolve this? Thank you.

Thank you for your response. I cant directlty give the base64 string as it is dynamic data and keep on changing. Is there any way to include like this??
